# Query to retrieve the top 2 columns which has the sum greater than the rest

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table which contains 5 rows a,b,c,d,e and i need to select the top 2 rows who's sum is greatest.

```
a b c d e 
1 3 4 5 6
8 6 7 8 9
5 4 9 0 1
```

so i need to get like

```
c  e
20 16
```

so i tried like

```
select top 2* sum(a),sum(b),sum(c),sum(d),sum(e) from tablename;
```

Comment: So are a,b,c,d,e rows or columns? Your text says rows, but the table example says columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union` to retrieve the columns with the 2 highest sums

```
select colName, colSum from (
    select 'a' colName, sum(a) colSum from mytable
    union all select 'b' colName, sum(b) colSum from mytable
    union all select 'c' colName, sum(c) colSum from mytable
    union all select 'd' colName, sum(d) colSum from mytable
    union all select 'e' colName, sum(e) colSum from mytable
) t1 order by colSum desc limit 2
```

However, this will return the values as two rows instead of one as in your example

```
colName, colSum
c, 20
e, 16
```

Comment: Thanks man FuzzyTree your solution is really awesome it was simple and clear.

Answer (score 0):

Consider restructuring your data as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,x CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,n INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (x,n) VALUES
('a',1), 
('a',8), 
('a',5), 
('b',3), 
('b',6), 
('b',4), 
('c',4), 
('c',7), 
('c',9), 
('d',5), 
('d',8), 
('d',0), 
('e',6), 
('e',9), 
('e',1);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+---+---+
| id | x | n |
+----+---+---+
|  1 | a | 1 |
|  2 | a | 8 |
|  3 | a | 5 |
|  4 | b | 3 |
|  5 | b | 6 |
|  6 | b | 4 |
|  7 | c | 4 |
|  8 | c | 7 |
|  9 | c | 9 |
| 10 | d | 5 |
| 11 | d | 8 |
| 12 | d | 0 |
| 13 | e | 6 |
| 14 | e | 9 |
| 15 | e | 1 |
+----+---+---+
```

Then the problem becomes trivial...

```
SELECT x
     , SUM(n) total_n 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY x 
 ORDER 
    BY total_n DESC 
 LIMIT 2;
+---+---------+
| x | total_n |
+---+---------+
| c |      20 |
| e |      16 |
+---+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks strawberry for the solution